Why my latex code for algorithm is showing End=0 in my project, whereas when I am running it alone it is working fine
Why my latex code of Algorithm is showing End=0 in end, when I am integrating the project in my code. Whereas when I run the algorithm alone it is working fine. Below is the piece of code
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Pseudocode for S-NOA}
\label{alg:SNOA}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE{Mapped data $(\lambda^{\text{map}}_v)$}
%\STATE \textbf{Input:} Mapped data $(\lambda^{\text{map}}_v)$
\ENSURE{ Reduced data $(\Phi_i)$}
\STATE \textbf{Begin}
\STATE \textbf{Initialize} $(V_j)$
\WHILE{$it \leq \textit{it}_{\text{max}}$}
    \FOR{each $(V_j)$}
        \STATE \textbf{Compute} $V_{j,s}$ using equation (\ref{eq:ubs})
        \STATE \textbf{Find} fitness function $F = \min(Cl) \ast F(V_j)$
        \STATE \textbf{Discover} the value of $\wp$ using equation (\ref{eq:phi})
        \STATE \textbf{Derive} the searching of nutcrackers for good seeds $V_j^{it+1}$
        \STATE \textbf{Estimate} seeds stored by nutcrackers
         $V_j^{(it+1)\text{new}}$ can be derived by equation (\ref{eq:Vnew})
        \IF{$\mathcal{\wp} > Pr_1$}
            \STATE $V_j^{it+1}$
        \ELSE
            \STATE $V_j^{(it+1)\text{new}}$
        \ENDIF
        \STATE \textbf{Perform} seed searching and cache recovery
        \STATE \textbf{Find} $V_{j,s}^{it+1}$
        \STATE \textbf{Balance} exploration and development process by using $Pr_2$
    \ENDFOR
\ENDWHILE
\STATE \textbf{Obtain} $(\Phi_i)$
\STATE \textbf{End}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}


I want my algorithm code should run fine while integrating in my project and should not show END=0, just END.

Please show a [mre] which actually reproduces the problem.

might be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147619/algoritmic-return-command-0

I figured out as I was using \Algpseudocodex package when I removed that, my porblem got resolved.
